# How to check a binary tree is BST or not?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am trying to determine if a binary tree is BST or not. My idea is while doing inorder traversal if the data is sorted then it is BST otherwise not. So that's why while doing inorder traversal I have inserted the values in a vector. then Checked it is sorted or not. If sorted then return true otherwise return false.

```
vector<int>vect;
void preOrder(node *current)
{
    if(current==NULL) return;

    preOrder(current->left);
    cout<<current->roll<<endl;
    vect.push_back(current->roll);
    preOrder(current->right);


}

bool checkBST(node *current)
{
    preOrder(current);
    int c=0;
    for(int i=1;i<vect.size();i++)
    {
        if(vect[i]>=vect[i-1])
        {
            continue;
        }

        else
        {
            c=1;
        }



    }

    if(c==1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

 // cout<<c<<endl;
}
```

is there anything wrong with my idea?

Comment: It's very inefficient. It's enough to find the first unordered node _during traversal_ to determine that the tree is not in order. You don't need to push anything to a vector.

Comment: I am just trying to capitalize on my idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an easier way. Write a function that checks if a given subtree is a BST and all of the nodes are within a given range.

```
// Checks if the tree rooted at current is a BST and
// all nodes are between low and high
bool checkBST(node* current, int low = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
    int high = std::numeric_limits<int>::max())
{
    // Check for empty subtree
    if (!current)
    {
        return true;
    }
    // Check if current node is in range
    return current->roll >= low && current->roll <= high
        // Check if all nodes in the left subtree is less than current node
        && checkBST(current->left, low, current->roll - 1)
        // Check if all nodes in the right subtree is greater than current node
        && checkBST(current->right, current->roll + 1, high);
}
```

Comment: @imtinan Just modify the bounds in the recursive call to allow for equal values.

Comment: If you have duplicate values -- you don't really have a BST...